# Cypress Gitlab CI/CD integration without docker executor?

Tags: testing, gitlab, cypress, cicd

Currently setting up Cypress in my teams project and am trying to set up our tests in our gitlab pipelines. Cypress has docker images with everything you need installed on it, but that only works if you use a docker executor for your gitlab runner. My organization does not allow that citing security issues, so we use a shell executor for everything. Has anyone else had an issue like this? Been researching for a few days and the only thing I can think of is using the kubernetes executor and somehow run the tests with that.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that will come across this later, what we did to solve this was install docker on the runners and build a docker image that runs the tests.